# SSH client with instant input echo

Tags: ssh, command-line, remote, latency

When using the terminal on `code-server` (VSCode probably does it as well), input is instantly shown on screen (grayed out,  until the server actually responds):

[image: screenshot of code-server]

When I connect to the remote machine using the OpenSSH client, however, the input is echoed only after a short delay. That's usually not very noticeable when latency is low, but makes it hard to type on slower connections.

Using the `-T` option to disable TTY allocation solves the issue, but severely limits the usability of the terminal.

Is there any SSH client with a similar feature to `code-server`?

Comment: I think [mosh](https://mosh.org) is supposed to have something like that, but I don't think I ever saw it work too well. YMMV. Something like that might also be implemented on the terminal emulator instead of the SSH client. (mosh effectively being both...)

Comment: @ilkkachu `mosh` seems to be what I'm looking for, but it doesn't support `ProxyJump` yet [[1](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/970)] [[2](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/285)] (which I currently rely on). I might try using a VPN instead. Regardless, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Why would you want this feature in the ssh client instead of in the terminal program?

Comment: @SottoVoce No reason in particular. I'd accept a terminal emulator as an answer too.